# ConnectApi Bulkified class

Tags: connect-api

In my org ConnectApi.FeedItem used in many places so I think we can have general class to make it work from different logics to avoid duplicate code.

so for that i created a class and implement that logics but for single post its working fine but when i used in a batch class its not working so can any one suggest me how do we do that :

here is my code:

```
    public  class WrapperConnectApi {

    public static void feedItem(String subId,String mentionId,String msge){

        List<ConnectApi.BatchInput> inputs=new List<ConnectApi.BatchInput>();

        ConnectApi.FeedItemInput input = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
        input.subjectId = subId;  

        ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput mentionSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.MentionSegmentInput();
        mentionSegmentInput.id =mentionId; //  chatterGroup.Id;

        ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput body = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
        body.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();

        ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegment = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
        textSegment.text =' '+ msge; 
        body.messageSegments.add(mentionSegmentInput);
        body.messageSegments.add(textSegment);
        input.body = body;

        ConnectApi.BatchInput batchInput = new ConnectApi.BatchInput(input);
        inputs.add(batchInput);

    if(inputs.size() > 0) 
            ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElementBatch(Network.getNetworkId(), inputs);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say it doesn't work, what exactly happens? Do you get an error message?

In the above code you are creating only 1 feed item input.

See this code example for how to post a batch of feed elements

```
    trigger postFeedItemToAccount on Account (after insert) {
    Account[] accounts = Trigger.new;

    // Bulk post to the account feeds.

    List<ConnectApi.BatchInput> batchInputs = new List<ConnectApi.BatchInput>();

    for (Account a : accounts) {
        ConnectApi.FeedItemInput input = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();

        input.subjectId = a.id;

        ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput body = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
        body.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();

        ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegment = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();
        textSegment.text = 'Let\'s win the ' + a.name + ' account.';

        body.messageSegments.add(textSegment);
        input.body = body;

        ConnectApi.BatchInput batchInput = new ConnectApi.BatchInput(input);
        batchInputs.add(batchInput);
    }

    ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElementBatch(Network.getNetworkId(), batchInputs);
}
```

Its from the [Salesforce Help Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/connectapi_examples_post_feed_element_batch.htm)